# For Each loop in Excel VBA finishes after only two iterations

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, foreach

I have written a very small macro which Is supposed to run VLOOKUP formula on a range of cells if the cell in the next column is empty.

My problem is, I run the `For Each` loop and it is working, but after 2 iterations the macro finishes. It is supposed to carry on checking each cell.

```
Sub copyFormula()

Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Variant

i = 4

For Each cell In Sheets

cell = Range("B" & i)

    If Not (IsEmpty(cell)) Then
     Range("C" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],Locations!C[-2]:C[-1],2,FALSE)"
     Else: Range("B" & i).Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End If
    
    i = i + 1
    
Next cell

End Sub
```

This is how the workbook looks like:

[image]

Comment: It's because your `cell` represents sheets, not cells. You loop through every sheet. Also, you will not want to loop through every cell in a sheet. You should specify the exact range which you want to loop.

Comment: Could you advise please, what do I have to add or change in order to fix this problem - referring to sheets instead of cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will loop through every cell of the activated sheet in range `B4:B100`. If it is empty it will add the formula to column `C`.

```
Sub copyFormula()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("B4:B100")
  If Not (IsEmpty(cell)) Then
    cell.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],Locations!C[-2]:C[-1],2,FALSE)"
  End If
Next

End Sub
```